# Implementing Google Vision API with Flutter

Tags: flutter, barcode, zxing, google-vision

I'm unsure of how to incorporate this into an existing flutter project and I haven't been able to find any useful guides or tips online.  Im looking to implement a 2D only barcode scanner, and none of the existing flutter barcode scanners have that option.

I know ZXing also has the 2d only functionality in it so I could be swayed to use that if anyone can point me in the direction of how to implement them in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Please check this url

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qrcode_reader
Here is implementation code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qrcode_reader/QRCodeReader.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'QRCode Reader Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  final Map<String, dynamic> pluginParameters = {
  };

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> _barcodeString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('QRCode Reader Example'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
          child: new FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _barcodeString,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                return new Text(snapshot.data != null ? snapshot.data : '');
              })),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _barcodeString = new QRCodeReader()
                .setAutoFocusIntervalInMs(200)
                .setForceAutoFocus(true)
                .setTorchEnabled(true)
                .setHandlePermissions(true)
                .setExecuteAfterPermissionGranted(true)
                .scan();
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Reader the QRCode',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example throws an error when i try to implement it:
E/flutter ( 4428): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4428): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method readQRCode on channel qrcode_reader)
E/flutter ( 4428): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter ( 4428): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4428): #1      QRCodeReader.scan (package:qrcode_reader/QRCodeReader.dart:67:27)
E/flutter ( 4428): <asynchronous suspension>

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using flutter [barcode_scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan) dependency.

```
Future _openQRScanner() async {
try {
  // Below code will open camera preview and return result after qr scan 
  String _content = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  setState(() => this._content = _content);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
    showSnackBar('Please grant camera permission!');
    setState(() {
      this._content = null;
    });
  } else {
    showSnackBar('Error: $e');
    setState(() {
      this._content = null;
    });
  }
} on FormatException {
  showSnackBar('User pressed "back" button before scanning');
  setState(() {
    this._content = null;
  });
} catch (e) {
  showSnackBar('Error: $e');
  setState(() {
    this._content = null;
  });
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please find the [repo](https://github.com/flutter-devs/flutter_qr_code_scanner).

If you want to take a look at Flutter you can find some good examples at our [companie’s Github](https://github.com/flutter-devs) page. Also, you can check our company's page [FlutterDevs](http://www.flutterdevs.com/).